# is it possible to import vue component from public folder?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried to create a embed widget to other website. I using vue js.. i wanna to import my vue component in `src/components/dashboard/widget/BasicWidget.vue` to my `widget.js` on public folder. but im not sure it can be load. and i don't know how to display it

**this is my `widget.js` file**

```
import widget1 from '../src/components/dashboard/widget/WidgetWideLargeCircular.vue'
```

and I tried to show in I frame like this on Jsfiddle

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/widget.js" width="300" height="600" align="left" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can't do it. You will not be able to load a vue component to pure js.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Perfectionist I decided to use iframe.. but there's way to load just component??

Comment: @Yusuf, there is no way to load vue component in js file. You can load in Vue component in other vue component.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-runtime-template-compiler or https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/